# Is there an inbuilt or canonical way in Rust to ‘publish’ state?

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, channel

Is there any canonical way in Rust to publish a frequently updating ‘state’ such that any number of consumers can read it without providing access to the object itself?

My use case is that I have a stream of information coming in via web socket and wish to have aggregated metrics available to consume by other threads. One could do this externally with something like Kafka, and I could probably roll my own internal solution but wondering if there is any other method?

An alternative which I’ve used in Go is to have consumers register themselves with the producer and each receive a channel, with the producer simply publishing to each channel separately. There will generally be a low number of consumers so this may well work, but wondering if there’s anything better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a "broadcast channel".

If you're using `async`, the popular `tokio` crate provides an implementation in their [`sync::broadcast`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) module:

> A multi-producer, multi-consumer broadcast queue. Each sent value is seen by all consumers.
>
> A `Sender` is used to broadcast values to all connected `Receiver` values. `Sender` handles are clone-able, allowing concurrent send and receive actions. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> New `Receiver` handles are created by calling `Sender::subscribe`. The returned `Receiver` will receive values sent after the call to `subscribe`.

If that doesn't quite suit your fancy, there are other crates that provide similar types that can be found by searching for ["broadcast"](https://crates.io/keywords/broadcast) on crates.io.

Comment: Aha, I had in my head those channels were “first consumer to read gets it and no one else”. That does the trick perfectly then!